# how to get data from input in modal html?

Tags: php, html

Trying to get trkodep from input and post it to /ppp/trkodeptoyek but when I push the button it's doesn't go to /ppp/trkodeproyek but it stay in form where I put the modal (it's like I only close the modal).

```
 <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek';?>" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek"/>
      <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Comment: Can you provide the rendered `html` code by one you have given?

Comment: I assume based on your class names that you are leveraging the Bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  <div class="modal-body">
  <form method="POST"  action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek">
  <input type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek"/>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Javascript:

```
 <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="form" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek';?>" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek"/>
      <input type="submit" onclick="form_submit()">
    </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function form_submit() {
    document.getElementById("form").submit();
   }    
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`base_url` is not a builtin function. so I can't know where you want.

If you want to go to the path under the current page, use relative path.

```
<form action="ppp/trkodeproyek" method="POST">
```

If `ppp` is under the root path, add a slash at beginning.

```
<form action="/ppp/trkodeproyek" method="POST">
```

Comment: base_url() to read my localhost. this is the result of my base_url   <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/PPP/index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek">

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div class="modal-body">
      <form action="<?PHP echo base_url().'index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek'; ?>" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek">
      <input type="submit">
      </form>
</div>
```

Or change the `form tag` into this `<form action="<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek" method="POST">`

- Make sure that the function`base_url()` is returning some value, if you are not sure, use `<?PHP echo base_url(); ?>` outside of the form and look if it is retuning some value
- **in your web browser, give right click in the textbox and select inspection, look what is the full URL of the action of the form**

Comment: this is the result from my base_url() <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/PPP/index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek">

Comment: I am so blind, indise the URL `index.php` should not be in the middle of the URL, your URL should something like this `"localhost:8080/PPP/ppp/trkodeproyek/SOMEFILE.PHP"` make sure what is the real path of the file what is recieving the data of the form

Comment: im trying to go to trkodeproyek (my function). and this is what inside of my function redirect('ppp/asset?trk=1'); ...

Comment: are you using some software to build that form? In the form tag you use action, that implies that  the form will send the information of the form and redirect to file that is inside of 'action'....

Comment: im using code igniter, yeah I want the form give information from input (trkodep) and then I can use trkodep for my function. but I want to redirect to ('ppp/asset?trk=1'); first, so I only create that code for my function. but that code doens't work and still redirect to the main form and can't go to  ('ppp/asset?trk=1');

Comment: I don't get at all your explanation, could you please try to reformulate your explanation. `asset?trk=1` means nothing for me, maybe `asset.php?trk=1` is something, that indicates that in the file `asset.php`  you are sending the value `1`  with id=`trk` through the URL.

Answer (score 0):

is your function to get the value from that form is on index.php? then if it yes, use this

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <form action="<?php echo base_url().'/ppp/trkodeproyek';?>" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek"/>
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my form action doesn't work here so I using `<a>` and javascript for direct to my function, and it's work.

```
 <input class="trkode" type="text" name="trkodep" placeholder="kode proyek"/>


      <a class="btn btn-default btntrk" href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek';?>" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">kirim</a>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function form_submit() {
          document.getElementById("form").submit();
        }
        $(".trkode").change(function(){
            //alert('anda telah memasukan kode proyek');
            var trkode = $(this).val();
            $(".btntrk").attr("href", "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/ppp/trkodeproyek/';?>"+trkode);
        });   
      </script>
```